# Can we make a variable work as a getter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript we can write:

```js
var obj = {
  log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],

  get latest() {
    if (this.log.length == 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
}

console.log(obj.latest); // Outputs "c"
```

> From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Now, I have to call `obj[key]` to make the `getter` work. Now:

```
let obj = {
    get root () {
        return 2
    }
}

console.log(obj) // Returns { root: [Getter] }, I would like it to return "2"
```

Can we make `obj` return `2` in some way?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "getter"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the function you need to call it using `obj.root`

```js
let obj = {
  get root() {
    return 2
  }
}

console.log(obj.root)
```

On the other hand you could simply write `obj = obj.root`

```js
let obj = {
  get root() {
    return 2
  }
}
obj = obj.root
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) to run the fuction as soon as it is defined.

```js
let obj = {
    root: (function() {
        return 2;
    })()
}

console.log(obj);
```

This will give the desired output. Note that in this case the IFFE does not add much value as it would be the same as simply defining `root: 2` on the object.

Comment: This is a good answer if he doesn't necessary want a getter function called `root` :-)

Comment: This is basically a (immediately invoked) getter function. Besides the fact that getters don't accept arguments, they're just syntactic sugar.